# $C^n[a,b]$ is a Banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Prove that $C^n[a,b]$ with pointwise multiplication of functions and a norm defined as $\displaystyle\|x\| = \sum_0^n \dfrac{\|x^{(k)}\|_{\infty}}{k!}$  is a Banach algebra.
As I understand I need to prove that a) $C^n[a,b]$ is complete, b) it's algebra (?) and c) $\|x\cdot y\| < \|x\|\cdot\|y\|$, but I'm not sure how to do it...

Comment: Have you been able to make progress?

Comment: @G.Chiusole no(

Comment: Do you know what you need to do in order to show any of those properties?

Comment: @G.Chiusole kind of, I mean I know definition of complete space and all, but it doesn't help me to use it in my case. Or I wouldn't ask